# Handling JSON in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to learn Swift and am struggling with understanding a piece about handling JSON and get "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" from using this code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let urlPath = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/marine.ashx?key=45e8e583134b4371a2fa57a9e5776&format=xml&q=45,-2"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        println("Task completed")
        if ((error) != nil) {
            println(error)

        } else {
            var err: NSError?
            println("URL: \(url)")

            var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary

            println(jsonResult)
        }


    })

    task.resume()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

The API key I'm using is free so don't worry about using it. The JSON results should look [something like this](http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/marine.ashx?key=45e8e583134b4371a2fa57a9e5776&format=xml&q=45,-2) but I am instead greeted with:

```
Task completed    
URL: http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/marine.ashx?key=45e8e583134b4371a2fa57a9e5776&format=xml&q=45,-2
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I'm assuming the jsonResult variable is what's causing the problem, but even if I try to force unwrap it (I think that's what I'm doing?) with something like

```
var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
```

it still fails with "expected type after 'as'."

Comment: `http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/marine.ashx?key=45e8e583134b4371a2fa57a9e5776&format=xml&q=45,-2` returns XML, not JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fail-able here, a website can even return 200 but return nothing, the data can come corrupted, and, in your case, I tried calling the URL you are using and found out, it's actually XML, so... there's your problem?

A more robust approach (assuming that you still want to parse JSON, maybe from another site? [The ISS has an open API](http://open-notify.org/Open-Notify-API/ISS-Location-Now/)) is to use the `if let` to unwrap optionals and then on the else case deal with the errors, rather than `!` your way to success.

Here's a very extensive check of everything

```
task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url), completionHandler: { [unowned self] (data, response :NSURLResponse!, errorRequest) -> Void in
    // Check the HTTP Header
    if let responseHTTP = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse
    {
        if responseHTTP.statusCode != 200
        {
            println("Received status code \(responseHTTP.statusCode)")
            return
        }
    }
    else
    {
        println("Non-HTTP Response received")
        return
    }

    var errorParsing : NSError?

    if let JSON = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: &errorParsing) as? NSDictionary
    {
        // Do the parsing
    }
    else
    {
        println("Error parsing: \(errorParsing)")
    }
})

task!.resume()
```

Comment: Holy cow. Yeah, the problem is definitely related to the fact that I was trying to parse XML as JSON. http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/marine.ashx?key=45e8e583134b4371a2fa57a9e5776&format=json&q=45,-2 works!

Answer (score 1):

`NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData...` returns an optional `NSData?`. This means that you can't cast it directly to `NSDictionary`. To fix the crash you will need to use `?as` which means your `jsonResult` will either be a `NSDictionary` or `nil`

`var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) ?as NSDictionary`

In your case, you can safely unwrap the optional by doing this.

`var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)`

```
if let jsonResult = jsonResult ?as NSDictionary {
println(jsonResult)
}
```